# Ansible module and tags on single line

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2, code-formatting

Consider these ansible tasks:

```yaml
- import_tasks: foo/spam.yml
  tags: foo, spam
- import_tasks: foo/ham.yml
  tags: foo, ham
- import_tasks: foo/eggs.yml
  tags: foo, eggs
```

Is it possible to write those on single lines, e.g. (doesn't work)

```yaml
- import_tasks: foo/spam.yml tags="foo, spam"
- import_tasks: foo/ham.yml  tags="foo, ham"
- import_tasks: foo/eggs.yml tags="foo, eggs"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your playbook needs to use valid YAML syntax. Since YAML is a superset of JSON, you could write:

```
- {"import_tasks": "foo/spam.yml", "tags": "foo, spam"}
- {"import_tasks": "foo/ham.yml", "tags": "foo, ham"}
- {"import_tasks": "foo/eggs.yml", "tags": "foo, eggs"}
```

Comment: *"YAML is a superset of JSON"* Mind blown. You just helped me level up. Thanks larsks!